# update.rc-d init.d startup script is not starting

Tags: 10.04, server, startup, init, init.d

I got a simple script called `hwtestinit` which I installed using

```
update-rc.d hwtestinit defaults
```

On the surface, as far as I can inspect, all seems fine , I mean, the following files, all exists, etc.

```
/etc/rc0.d/K20hwtestinit -> ../init.d/hwtestinit
/etc/rc1.d/K20hwtestinit -> ../init.d/hwtestinit
/etc/rc6.d/K20hwtestinit -> ../init.d/hwtestinit
/etc/rc2.d/S20hwtestinit -> ../init.d/hwtestinit
/etc/rc3.d/S20hwtestinit -> ../init.d/hwtestinit
/etc/rc4.d/S20hwtestinit -> ../init.d/hwtestinit
/etc/rc5.d/S20hwtestinit -> ../init.d/hwtestinit
```

When I run the script manually, all seems fine, that is, issuing the command

```
/etc/init.d/hwtestinit start
```

Yields to the desired results.However, system is not executing the on startup, and I have no idea why. I could not find any mention of it at logs files found under /var/log and wonder ins which other log file I should look at.

The script is dumped below

```
#! /bin/sh

case "$1" in
  start)
    smarteventd -c /etc/sctest.ini
    lcdaemon --lcdtest    
    ;;
  stop)
    smarteventd --stop
    lcdaemon --stop
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/hwtestinit {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Why do you expect to find something in log files? Nothing is logged if not explicitly requested. Put some `echo "msg" >>/var/log/mylog` around to see what happens.

Comment: @enzotib I would expect system V to log if it fails or skip a task,  wouldn't you?

Comment: Maybe mark the question as answered since you've switched to using upstart?

Comment: @SpamapS SO does not let one mark self answer before 24 hours passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) instead of system V.

Things work fine now. Quite strange though.

Answer (score 3):

The output of sysv init scripts *should* end up in /var/log/boot.log. You would want to look in there for any output.